# Properly handling async selector options in an Angular form control

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<label>Field Name</label>
<select [formControl]="valItem.controls.Output">
  <option *ngFor="let v of aMap.get(item.id)?.availFields" [value]="v.Field">{{v.Field}}
  </option>
</select>

ngOnChanges(): void {
  this.aService.someCall(someVar)
  .subscribe(
  (response: any) => {
     this.aMap.set(id, response);
  });
}
```

So in the DOM I am using values in the selector dropdown that come asynchronously from some service. For whatever reason, every once in a while the service takes too long--even though it does put the values into the aMap once it gets a response--but the dropdown will remain empty. It doesn't seem to 'refresh' itself once there are values to show. How can I handle this correctly so that once the data comes back, the dropdown has values in it and is not empty?

Comment: can you share the component code. please. this might help

Comment: I would discourage calling methods in the template. It will be called every time change detection is run, which is often and would cause your browser to crash. I'd use variables in template and handle all else login in the Component.

Comment: Then why doesn't change detection populate the dropdown when there is data in it?

Comment: well it's hard to tell anything based on the code you are presenting, please share the TS code as well.

Comment: What is `item`? You are accessing `item.id`